# Search Java lib: HTML to Excel

Tags: java, excel

I´m looking for a Java library which converts HTML content to Excel.
I have searched on the internet, but I haven´t found so many libs.

I found the following lib:
https://github.com/alanhay/html-exporter

But it seems that it has not been updated for 7 years.

Is there any lib in place which I can use for this purpose?

Comment: You may check [Spire.XLS for Java](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/xls-for-java.html) library and this example code: ```Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        workbook.loadFromHtml("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Input.html");
        workbook.saveToFile("ToExcel.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2016);```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatelly also not for free or at least there are restrictions at the free version